# XSLT 1.0 select value-of in node set with string

Tags: xslt

I have some trouble with selecting values in node set. I have a string variable,
which concatenate in path of next existed node in xml. But when i try to select valu from it,
it results in paste of value of this variable, not the value of node. I can`t find how i can
convert string to node set for proper selection. Please, help.

```
<xsl:for-each select="result/node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="./node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="rating">
                    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="translate(
                                       substring(.,1,3),
                                       $upCase,
                                       $lowCase
                                    ) = 'id_'">
                        <xsl:value-of  select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:variable name="cval"
                                      select="concat(
                                                 '/survey/checkbox_value/',
                                                 local-name(),
                                                 '/.'
                                              )" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cval" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please paste your code example, it might be more helpful to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything. It could be done with plain xpath.

```
<xsl:variable name="local_name" select="local-name()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="/survey/checkbox_value/node()[
                         local-name() = $local_name
                      ]"/>
```

Comment: But if you really want to use dynamic xpaths check out exslt dynamic extenstions (dyn:evaluate). For example: `dyn:evaluate(concat('/survey/checkbox_value/',local-name()))`. Just remember that you can have no exslt libraries installed on target server.

Comment: 2 Gleb M Borisov: XSLT 1.0 is only available, so i can`t use extentions(

Comment: Check out my answer's text. There are no extensions used, just plain XPath 1.0. Anyway, dyn:evaluate is part of exslt library (http://exslt.org/). If you're using libxslt on *nix - just install it from your package manager (in ubuntu/debian: `sudo apt-get install libexslt`).